# Ionic Expandable list with buttons

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm looking how to do an expandable list that contain buttons inside. I have seen some tutorials,but they have just expandable list with items.

Comment: Ionic team does not provided yet Ionic expandable list, you can try like this https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-an-accordion-list-in-ionic/

Comment: I have seen,thanks